# how to determine pytables filename from table

Tags: python, pytables

I have an application where I pass a table instance (or "node") around.  I need to know the filename of the parent file in some places along the way.  I can't seem to find a built-in method to return this.  Is it possible?

for example, I am looking for the 'get_parent_file' functionality below:

```
import tables

f = tables.openFile("myfile.h5", 'r')

t = f.root.a

f = t.get_parent_file()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `t._v_file.filename` gives you the filename.